# XPath expression of serialized XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a custom object that I have serialized to XML.

The class structure looks like this:

```
public partial class MyWebForm : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [DataContract, Serializable]
    public class MyObjectRoot
    {
        public MyObjectRoot(List<MyObject> myobjects)
        {
            this.Objects = myobjects;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public List<MyObject> Objects { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract, Serializable]
    public class MyObject
    {
        public MyObject(string property1, string property2, string property3)
        {
            this.Property1 = property1;
            this.Property2 = property2;
            this.Property3 = property3;
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string Property1 { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Property2 { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The serialized XML looks like this:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <MyWebForm.MyObjectRoot xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyApplication">
<Objects>
    <MyWebForm.MyObject>
      <Property1>Testing123</Property1>
      <Property2>Testing456</Property2>
      <Property3>Testing789</Property3>
    </MyWebForm.MyObject>
  </Objects>
</MyWebForm.MyObjectRoot >`
```

Can I use XPath to get the nodes on a serialized XML file? If so what would be the expression to grab each property of my object, aka the values in my MyWebForm.MyObject?

So far I have tried this and no luck:

```
XPath("MyWebForm.MyObjectRoot/Objects/MyWebForm.MyObject/Property1[1]")
```

Comment: Are trying to get a collection of property elements, or a collection their of values?

Comment: I'm using the Xpath in an ItemTemplate for a ListView control. So to answer your question, it would be a collection of the values

Answer (score 2):

This xpath `//*[starts-with(name(), 'Property')]` should work.

using  Linq2Xml :

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring); //or XDocument.Load(xmlfile);
var properties = xDoc.XPathSelectElements("//*[starts-with(name(), 'Property')]")
                     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an Xpath statement that will get the values of all the children of MyWebForm.MyObject

```
MyWebForm.MyObjectRoot/Objects/MyWebForm.MyObject/*/text()
```